# Quantization of a massless scalar

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, s-matrix-theory

Let $t$:time, $r$:distance, and $u=t-r$.
Since any massless particle should propagate along u=const. , we need to change the asymptotic infinity of a massless scalar from time infinity to null infinity. This implies that the quantization of a massless scalar must be adjusted accordingly. For example, I think the LSZ formula should not be expressed as
$$a(t=\infty)-a(t=-\infty)=-i\int d^3\mathbf{k}~f(\mathbf{k})\int d^4x~e^{ikx}(-\partial^2)\phi(x),$$
but rather in terms of $u$ and $r$, like
$$a(r=\infty,u,\mathbf{x})-a(r=-\infty,u,\mathbf{x})=~?$$
However, I cannot find any textbook or resources discussing this modification. Can anyone provide insights on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using the standard coordinates $(t,x)$ to construct a quantum field theory is perfectly reasonable and the LSZ formula is these coordinates is a perfectly rigorous piece of mathematics.

The coordinates $(u,v) = (x-t,x+t)$, called light-cone coordinates, can also be used to construct relativistic quantum theories. This is called light-cone quantization. It is essentially equivalent to the use of standard coordinates, but may be more practical in some cases (and probably less practical in some other situations). This technique is not covered in introductory textbooks on QFT as it is not needed there. It is, however, often covered in textbooks on string theory as it allows to compute by hand the string spectrum and before developing more advanced techniques.

There seem to be some applications of lightcone quantization in QFT, like [here](https://indico.cern.ch/event/1203236/contributions/5061499/attachments/2550983/4394345/Lectures_LFPT_HE_QCD_1.pdf) and the references therein.